# Using MySQL as back end with ApacheDS

Tags: mysql, apacheds

Is it possible to configure MySQL as back end data storage with ApacheDS? I could not find anything on this online. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support by default for SQL backend.